# How large current is needed to get a voltage change over a capacitor?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current

First off, this is question from my homework.

I'm not sure I understand the question, wouldn't the needed current be > 0?

Comment: You need *charges* for the voltage to change. Charge = Current * time. So any non-zero current applied for a non-zero time will change the voltage.

Comment: @Viktor: Edit your question to include the _whole_ text of your question. There's got to be more than you have given us. Then show how you have tried to solve it so far.

Comment: No, really, this is it. The headline is Theory questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two equations to consider with Capacitors

1. Q = CV
2. \$I = C\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}\$

Likewise

1. Q = It

For there to be a voltage across a capacitor which was initially 0V, there must be a charge flow. How much voltage in a given time would dictate the current required.

Comment: Does the current needed depend on the voltage over the capacitor?

Comment: Current through a capacitor is never dependent on the voltage, ,only on the rate of change of voltage, like JonRB already said: I=Cdu/dt.